# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, прямая-речь, сложное-предложение

*— Ты — скучный, посредственный зануда, — выплёвывает Ромка, ловя на себе взгляд готового расплакаться от такого Саши, чёрт возьми, он был такой грустный...*

Поправьте, пожалуйста, если что-то не так.

Comment: Такая пунктуация допустима.

Answer (score 2):

– *Ты – скучный, посредственный зануда,– выплёвывает Ромка, ловя на себе взгляд готового расплакаться от такого Саши; **чёрт возьми, он был такой грустный**...*

Заключительная часть имеет явно присоединительный характер, там нужна пауза. Как ее обозначить? Тире не подойдет, так как здесь и так много тире, а скобки ставить не хочется. Предлагаю поставить точку с запятой.

Comment: В таких случаях можно обойтись просто запятой, если автор подчёркивает как бы один "поток мыслей", особенно когда передаётся чьё-то восприятие. К примеру, сравните с предложением из книги Н. Абгарян "С неба упали три яблока": https://i.imgur.com/JVkwG5H.png

Comment: А если не подчеркивает? Тогда в своем комментарии напишите автору: допустимо, если это поток сознания, ага? Я в этом не уверена –  это же все-таки не стандарт, а авторская фишка. Прием должен быть узнаваемым, должен повторяться.   Произношение без паузы должно быть тоже преднамеренным и понятым автору.  А если это просто некорректное оформление?

Comment: Я довольно часто этот приём встречал в литературе. Не в таком, конечно, масштабе, как у Абгарян, чаще всего в два, максимум в три звена. Но, насколько я понимаю, даже не будь тут авторского замысла, некорректным (с точки зрения правил пунктуации) нельзя такое написание назвать.

Comment: Можно назвать. Выглядит как  самостоятельная конструкция, похожая на несобственно-прямую речь. С какой стати присоединять ее обычной запятой.  Это вообще нестандартный вариант: уже не слова автора, но еще не прямая речь персонажа.

Answer (score 2):

Мне это предложение не видится удачным.

Первое.
*Скучный, посредственный зануда* — здесь, мне кажется, присутствует [плеоназм](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/160958).
Вот [синонимы](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-79522.htm) к слову "скучный": неинтересный, пресный, нудный, **занудный**...
Если это задумка такая, то ее нужно соответственно обыграть — вкупе с резким глаголом ***выплёвывать*** *(перен. разг.*: извергать, выбрасывать из себя).
Можно так:
— Ты скучный и посредственный. Зануда! — выплёвывает Ромка...
Или так:
— Ты — мутный, посредственный зануда! — выплёвывает Ромка...

Дальше.
*Ловя на себе взгляд готового расплакаться от такого Саши...* — нелегко читается и воспринимается. И от чего ж *такого*? Если от слов, то — таких, если от характеристики или оценки, то — такой.
Можно так: ловя на себе взгляд готового расплакаться Саши.
Или так: ловя на себе взгляд Саши, готового расплакаться от такого ярлыка.

Последнее.
*Выплёвывает, ловя* — это глагол и деепричастие в настоящем времени, глагол *был* — в прошедшем (думаю, правильно так: чёрт возьми, он такой грустный).
Правда, если кто-то готов расплакаться, то он уже не просто грустный, а потерянный, опустошенный, раздавленный.

Comment: Разобрали как Боженька, благодарю!

Comment: А по мне, так все прекрасно! Только оформить надо переход. Мне нравится ваш стиль, он современный. Не все же писать, как Чехов и Толстой сто лет назад.  Скучно и надоело! Хочется чего-нибудь нового, интересных экспериментов, и все такое. Только вот правила не всегда просто подобрать, тогда надо ставить знаки по интонации. Вы паузу перед "черт возьми" делаете, подчеркиваете ее? Или все читаете практически в одну фразу?

Comment: Кстати, здесь разбор вообще не требовался, так что ответ НЕ ПО ТЕМЕ. Вопрос: "Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении?". Про знаки ни слова, в том числе про спорную запятую. А для этого грамматику нужно определить, она здесь нестандартная. Вот что важно и интересно.

Comment: Не мастер я ни в пикировке, ни в передвижничестве. Поэтому — https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZN27lqX12U. Если своими рассуждениями или своим бессылочным видением я кого-то зацепила, то приношу извинения.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова
 Тут  дело не в лицах, "цепляет идеология": Всех стричь одинаково! Я лучше знаю, как писателю надо писать".  И это при том, что уже идет обсуждение конкретного знака (самая наша тема!), высказаны два различных мнения и поэтому очень не помешала бы  еще одна точка зрения.

Answer (score 2):

И — последнее после последнего.
Привожу комментарий *Sharon*  (если он будет удалён, то никто ничего не поймёт), практически ей же и отвечаю.

> Кстати, здесь разбор вообще не требовался, так что ответ НЕ ПО ТЕМЕ. Вопрос: "Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении?". Про знаки ни слова, в том числе про спорную запятую. А для этого грамматику нужно определить, она здесь нестандартная. Вот что важно и интересно.

*Вопрос: "Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении?".*
Считаю, что точка после кавычек не нужна.

*Про знаки ни слова, в том числе про спорную запятую.*
"Дык" и в Вашем ответе ни про какие **знаки** нет ни слова, всего лишь про *одну-единственную*, именно спорную запятую: "...скобки ставить не хочется. Предлагаю поставить точку с запятой".
Да, именно она на самом деле и дискуссионна.
(Но, кстати, тут имеется еще одна непонятка от автора: *чёрт возьми, **он** был такой грустный...* Взгляд или Саша?)

Но Вы-то уже на эту тему порассуждали, поэтому я и заострила свое внимание на *другой* части вопроса: "Поправьте, пожалуйста, если что-то не так".
И попыталась объяснить испрашивающему — **что** же именно *не так* (по моему мнению).

По-Вашему же получается, что в вопросах про запятую я никоим образом не должна поправлять *чю-щю, масло масляное, стекляный-оловяный* и рассогласованность времен.
Не требовалось — и эхх! — значит, не по теме.
Да пусть живут "ошиббулечки" — ведь спрашивали вроде о пунктуации.

Comment: Спасибо за подробнейший разбор! Не ожидала, что грамотные люди ТАК запарятся, чтобы помочь не только с пунктуацией, а вообще со всем, что в предложении не так.

Answer (score 1):

**Второй ответ**

Я могу еще раз повторить: **ответ не по теме.** Ведь сказано в вопросе: «Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении? Поправьте, пожалуйста, если что-то не так». Куда же яснее?

Рассуждаем далее. **Как узнать, правильно или нет?** Строго говоря, это делается по общей методике. Следует определить грамматику, обосновать знаки по правилам, которые обычно ориентированы на грамматику, дать ссылку на источник. **Где всё это?**

Собственно говоря, все наше внимание в данном случае – **к запятой** перед оборотом речи в конце предложения. Содержание там понятно, идет повтор ранее сказанного: «готовый расплакаться», «он был такой грустный».

**А грамматика?**  Как ее определить?  Это уже не слова автора, а **мысли и эмоции персонажа в дословном изложении**, причем уже более поздняя оценка ситуации – то, что Ромке думалось как бы потом: «Чёрт возьми, он был такой грустный...»  Мы видим необычное построение предложения, **поиск новых форм.**

**Как же это оформить?** Ведь оборот не продолжает авторские слова, поэтому нужна пауза и более сильный знак, чем запятая.

**А точно ли нужна?** Может быть, действительно так и надо писать – поставить запятую, произносить без паузы? По структуре это такая **явная вставка**, что выделять ее знаками и не надо. Вот что остается неясным и в чем автор может нам помочь: **делается здесь пауза или нет**.

**А насчет «ошибочек и плеоназма» …**  У меня было такое впечатление, что художник-передвижник учит импрессиониста, как надо писать картины: «Здесь красочку не ту положили, и вот здесь тоже…»  Не наше это дело – художественную речь править, да еще явно новаторского стиля.

Но если уж очень хочется, то желательно давать материал **в конце ответа**, а не делать его основным контентом.